# Entrar en una entrada y al volver atrás aparece arriba wordpress

Tags: wordpress

en mi web al entrar a una entrada y después volver atrás me devuelve al principio del todo en el pc y en el móvil me aparece en el footer.

¿Cómo podría configurarlo para que me devolviera justo en el lugar que estaba del inicio antes de entrar a esa entrada que accedí?

Gracias por adelantado.

Dejo un video: https://streamable.com/19jdl

Curiosamente con el mismo tema minamaze en versión gratis si me recuerda la posición exacta al volver atrás.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega detalles a la misma. Actualmente es muy amplia y sin un [mcve] es difícil saber a lo que te refieres. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para añadir lo necesario. Saludos

Comment: Hola he subido un vídeo, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

conseguí solucionarlo investigando y rebuscando por los archivos de jquery, scripts de mi plantilla minamaze pro. Dejo la solución por si le pudiera servir a alguien en un futuro.

Reemplazar:wp-content/themes/Minamaze_Pro/lib/scripts Archivo: main-frontend

```
jQuery(‘html, body’).animate({scrollTop:0}, ‘slow’);
```

a

jQuery $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "1000px" });

Comment: Quito las comillas o dejo las comillas de la segunda línea que es como está ahora aplicado? por ahora no he notado ningún fallo

Comment: ah vale, esa línea era la antigua con la que no recordaba la posición exacta al volver atrás, ahora tengo esa línea sustituida por la segunda.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el cache y ahora no aparece el slider y no puedo abrir el menú desplegable desde el móvil

Comment: Lo único que he conseguido es anular los cambios y aplicar el script: <script>history.scrollRestoration = "manual"</script> con tracking script manager, así aparece arriba en el móvil en vez de en el footer como antes. Pero mi idea era conseguir que recordara la posición exacta sin tener otros problemas.

Comment: He conseguido que recuerde la posición y a su vez el menú no se vea afectado en el ordenador ni en el móvil, el único fallo ahora no carga el slider.

Comment: Lo he solucionado instalando un slider externo con un plugin